# How to describe JSON data in a spec?

Tags: json

What is the best way to describe JSON data in a spec?

In the past I've used examples with 'wordy' descriptions, but it feels imprecise.

There seems to be a nascent [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) standard, but it doesn't look like a hugely active project.  Any other ways?

---

(**Update**) After thinking about this for several days I like bmargulies suggestion around using a conversion convention.  Since the JSON documents in this case our coming out of .NET web services I am going to simply document the schema with C# class syntax.  This may not be totally rigourous, but everyone involved will understand it and coupled with the examples will get the message across as quickly as possible.

Comment: Do you need a standard way of specifying JSON schema or a formal way for writing tools for checking the data according to the spec?

Comment: Primarily I'd like a standard notation/syntax for consistency, and which others reading the spec would be familiar with already.  Tools for validating samples would be great too, and very useful for unit testing.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't lose the examples.  They _are_ the best way to describe your schema.  You need something else for all the corner cases, though.

Answer (score 24):

I would recommend my [js-schema](https://github.com/molnarg/js-schema/) JavaScript library. The primary motivation behind it was the same what you describe in the question. It is a simple and easy to understand notation to describe JSON schemas (or specification, if you want).

An example schema described in JSON Schema:

```json
{
  "type":"object",
  "properties":{
    "id":{
      "type":"number",
      "required":true
    },
    "name":{
      "type":"string",
      "required":true
    },
    "price":{
      "type": "number",
      "minimum":0,
      "required":true
    },
    "tags":{
      "type":"array",
      "items":{
        "type":"string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the same schema description with js-schema:

```json
{
  "id"    : Number,
  "name"  : String,
  "price" : Number.min(0),
  "?tags" : Array.of(String)
}
```

The library is able to validate object against schemas, generate random objects conforming to a given schema, and serialize/deserialize to/from JSON Schema.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an older question, but it might be useful to someone else:
When looking for methods to describe JSON-data I stumbled upon [Orderly](http://orderly-json.org/). Here's the abstract right of the front page:

> Orderly is a textual format for describing JSON. Orderly can be compiled into JSONSchema. It is designed to be easy to read and write.

I can agree with that, but I have only tried it with relatively simple structures so far.

Answer (score 7):

How about using some kind of extended BNF?

```
PERSON <- { "firstname": FIRSTNAMES, "lastname": LASTNAME, "age": AGE, "version": VERSION, "parents" <- PARENTS }

FIRSTNAMES <- [ FIRSTNAME+ ]

FIRSTNAME <- STRING

LASTNAME <- STRING

PARENTS <- [ PERSON{0,2} ]

AGE <- INTEGER

VERSION <- 1 | 2
```

You'd have to define the meaning of atomic type descriptions like INTEGER and STRING somewhere. If you wanted to add non-hardcoded keys for dictionaries, you would define that as follows:

```
BREADLOOKUP <- { (TYPE : HOWMANY)+ }

TYPE <- "white" | "dark" | "french" | "croissant"

HOWMANY <- POSITIVE-INTEGER
```

This would allow stuff like

```
{ "white": 5, 
  "french": 2
}
```

Since both regular expressions and BNF are pretty well known, this might be an easy way to 
go. `?`, `+`, `*`, `{n}`, `{min,max}` would be easy ways to specify a number of elements (taken from regexes) and the rest is pretty much pure BNF.

If you did that rigorously enough, it might even be parsable for a validator.

Comment: This would work, but it loses the inherent nesting of a JSON document and the overall structure requires a little too much thinking about (for me at least!)

Comment: Can you post an example of a json structure you'd like to describe?

Answer (score 1):

You could combine a W3C XML Schema, or some less ugly schema like RelaxNG, with conversion conventions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RelaxNG  ... but I like the idea of using a conversion convention.